# git push error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 403

Tags: git, ldap, push

I am trying to push my code from client(git bash) to git linux server with ldap authentication and it fails with below error

```
$ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 279 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 403
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Below is my virtual host entry

```
<VirtualHost <server ip>>
ServerName <server name>
LogLevel Debug
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/opt/git/repos
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv REMOTE_USER=$REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER
ScriptAlias /git /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend

<Directory "/usr/libexec/git-core*">
   Options ExecCGI Indexes
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*/git-receive-pack$">
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from All
        AuthName "GIT Repo"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://<servername>:501/ou=abc,dc=gd,dc=abcldap"
        Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am seeing below error in apache logs

```
[error] [client 10.112.111.25] client denied by server configuration: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
```

Not sure what is going wrong. Is it ldap connection error or git error. I just have 2 files in my project. I am able to clone. Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.